# ASP Classic INSERT/DELETE SQL Query No Error but Not Working

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have a simple ASP page that should delete or insert a row based on passed-in variables.  I have similar files that work fine, but this one does not work... even though there are no errors and the response.write checks work fine.  I even tried using literal values with no luck.  Any ideas?  Here is the code:

```
<%  
dim tid
dim email
dim joinOrUnjoin
tid = UCase(Request.Form("thisID"))
email = UCase(Request.Form("email"))
joinOrUnjoin = UCase(Request.Form("joinOrUnjoin"))

dim objConn
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=*********;Database=Reports;User Id=**********;Password=***********;"
objConn.mode = 3
objConn.Open

if LCase(joinOrUnjoin) = "join" then

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO SSOcomEmailDistribution (ID, Email) VALUES ('" & id & "', '" & email & "')"
    Response.write "Join"
else

    strSQL = "DELETE From SSOcomEmailDistribution WHERE ID='" & id & "' AND Email='" & email & "'"
    Response.write "Unjoin " & id & " " & email
end if

objConn.Execute(strSQL)
objConn.Close()

Response.write " Done"
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a variable named "tid" like this:

```
tid = UCase(Request.Form("thisID"))
```

but then, you use something else named "id" in your SQL string, like this:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO SSOcomEmailDistribution (ID, Email) VALUES ('" & id & "', '" & email & "')"
```

maybe just a typo, maybe something else is missing?

Comment: And it's a good idea to use Option Explicit to pinpoint this sort of mistake